# Performance in ENTITY FRAMEWORK

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-5

Sometimes when I'm writing queries using LINQ and if I use it inside of a loop. It turns so slow the performance.

```
        var query1 = from c in db.Classes
                     where c.TeacherId.Equals(teacherId)
                     select c;

        // AnsweredAssignment Query
        var query2 = (from c in db.AnsweredAssignments
                      where c.AssignmentId == assignmentId && c.Student.Class.TeacherId.Equals(teacherId)
                      select c).ToArray();

        // Tokens Query
        var query3 = (from c in db.Tokens
                      where c.AssignmentId == assignmentId && c.Student.Class.TeacherId.Equals(teacherId)
                      select c).ToArray();

        // OverwrittenScores Query
        var query4 = (from os in db.OverwrittenScores
                      where os.AssignmentId == assignmentId && os.Student.Class.TeacherId.Equals(teacherId)
                      select os).ToArray();



        foreach (var c in query1)
        {
            foreach (var s in c.Students)
            {
                var aaItems = (from aa in query2
                               where aa.StudentId == s.StudentId
                               select aa).ToArray();


                // Generate scores for objectives
                var id3 = (from aa in aaItems 
                           where !aa.IsMakeup
                           orderby aa.Score descending
                           select aa).FirstOrDefault();

                if (id3 != null)
                {
                    var aa3 = (from aa in query2
                               where aa.AnsweredAssignmentId == id3.AnsweredAssignmentId
                               select aa).SingleOrDefault();
                    ...
                }


                var tokens = (from t in query3
                              where t.StudentId == s.StudentId
                              select new MonitorByGeneralScoreToAnsweredAssignment(AssignmentStatus.Pending)).ToList();

                ...


                // does exist any overwritten score?
                var osItem = query4.Where(os => os.StudentId == s.StudentId).SingleOrDefault();

                ...
            }

        // OverwrittenScores Query
        var query4 = (from os in db.OverwrittenScores
                      where os.AssignmentId == assignmentId && os.Student.Class.TeacherId.Equals(teacherId)
                      select os).ToArray();
```

What I'm doing now is to get the records which I'm gonna use instead of getting one by one inside of the loop. Is this a good practice? Sometimes I guess that I'm not doing a good work :(

When I've got the records, I've save it into memory and using LINQ TO OBJECTS (from memory) I get to record.

Answer (score 0):

So remember that making calls to a database will always be slow. In fact, it's often the slowest part of most applications. Thus, you should strive to return a lot of stuff at once, rather than trying to get items one at a time.

Strive to rewrite your queries such that you return *as much of the required information in one go* as necessary. Although you might use up more memory, it's more often than not worth it for the time savings. Connecting to databases is slow!

Secondly, (last I checked) Entity Framework uses reflection to be able to set properties on your objects. Reflection is also very slow, which is why - despite EFs cool factor - I still prefer to do my queries by hand. The performance is just significantly faster (but of course introduces another layer of complication since now you're not only dealing with one language - C# - but two - C# and SQL - which are conceptually very different).